# React renderToNodeStream and gzip/br/deflate

Tags: reactjs, stream, gzip, server-side-rendering

Working on a SSR app using React/Express i'm trying to get a grip on renderToNodeStream and streams in general.

I have a large page (400kb not compressed) and using renderToNodeStream give a really good TTFB (time to first byte), all I miss is some compression to make the HTML response smaller sent back smaller but I cant make it work with renderToNodeStream.

am I missing something ?
Is it possible to stream freshly rendered responses AND compress them ?

```
const stream = renderToNodeStream(<MyApp/>)

// this doesn't work
stream.pipe(zlib.createGzip())
stream._flush = zlib.Z_SYNC_FLUSH

stream.pipe(
 res,
 { end: "false" }
)

// stream.on("data", data => {
//   console.log(data)
// })
stream.on("end", () => {
  res.end(pageEnd())
})
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) and [compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) middleware, you probably need to write

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
```

before streaming to the client.

As shown in [compression middleware code](https://github.com/expressjs/compression/blob/7e91b1821fde2d24e4614bfaaea6275e3de89005/index.js#L257), if `Content-Type` does not exist, the middleware won't compress the content.

The final code would be:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

const stream = renderToNodeStream(<MyApp/>)

stream.pipe(
 res,
 { end: "false" }
)

stream.on("end", () => {
  res.end(pageEnd())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertonodestream

**renderToNodeStream()** returns a readable stream. With this function you are assembling a snippet of HTML and send it to the users' browser and the process repeats.

The reason you may want to take this approach as you know is for performance, but I am not too sure if compression is a part of the process.